# Metallic surface render with white patches

Tags: rendering

I do not know what I'm doing wrong, my scissors render with white patches on it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi there : ). Can u add an image of your node setup of the scissors material?

Comment: Hello Nxd, picture with node setup added.

Comment: It looks like you have duplicated or overlapping geometry, creating z-fighting